importing enums from prisma returns undefined in testing environments
This problem happens in testing environments.
when I try to import an enum from @prisma/client it returns undefined...
import { DailyTip } from "@prisma/client";

describe("test", () => {
   it("should do something", () => {
      console.log(DailyTip) // undefined
   });
})

I'm using vitest with prisma over nodeJS.
prisma client has been deepMocked inside __mocks__ dir
Temporary Solution
I came up with the solution using vi.mock("@prisma/client")
vi.mock("@prisma/client", async (importOriginal) => {
  const actual: any = await importOriginal();
  return {
    ...actual,
    Difficulty: {
      DARK_SOULS: "DARK_SOULS",
      HARD: "HARD",
      MEDIUM: "MEDIUM",
      EASY: "EASY",
    },
  };
});

Objective
In my other routes. I import 10 enums in one file. I don't want to mock objects like this every time for testing purposes. there should be another easier way to do this. right? let me know if you need more code.
